# Formula to calculate if the date in one cell is greater than another cell not in date format

Tags: date, if-statement, formula

In cell B2, I have the format set as General.

Cell C46 has this formula: =TODAY()

The formula in cell B2 is: =TEXT(C46,"m")&" - "&TEXT(INDEX(Data!N:V,MATCH(G60,Data!V:V,0),2),"d")

what this formula does (at least i think), is combine two other cells that are also in General format.
The result is "1 - 5", which i'm happy with, because it gives the appearance of being a date

In cell A2, I have another formula, which is what i need help with.
I want the formula to look at the first number in cell B2 and read it as a Month.
Then, i want it to look at the second number in B2 (the number after the hyphen), and read it as a Day.

Finally, i want the formula in A2, which is reading B2 as a date, to tell me whether B2 is greater than or less than today's date.  If it is greater than, then mark as "Paid". If not, then "Not Paid"

=IF(DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2)<TODAY()),"Paid","Not Paid")

can't figure out why this isn't working though.  I even tried changing B2 into the below formula, but still doesn't work.

=TEXT(C46,"m")&" - "&TEXT(INDEX(Data!N:V,MATCH(G68,Data!V:V,0),2),"d")&" - "&YEAR(TODAY())

any help would be great.. please let me know if any of the above wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i managed an improvement over what i was looking for.
so this formula will tell me that if the date has passed, the bill has been paid.
if the date has not passed, it will tell me how many days until the bill is due

=IF(DATEVALUE(B68)<TODAY(),"Paid",IF(TODAY()>B68,"Paid","Due in "&B68-TODAY()&" days"))

looks like it's working after a few tests, but if anyone sees any problems or a way to improve it, i would love to know.